# Join two dataframes from a conditional row

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1
            A       B
0        0.00  514.51
1        0.75  514.51
2        1.10  514.42
3        3.52  514.41
4        5.59  514.43

df2
            A       B
0        2.00  520.00
1        3.00  521.00
2        4.00  524.00
3        5.00  529.00
4        6.00  531.00
5        7.00  532.00
```

I need to create a new `df3`, with next conditions:

- From `df1`: all datas.
- From `df2`: datas from last `df1` `A` value (I mean, last `df1` `A` value is 5.59; first `df2` `A` value I want to include in new `df3` would be 6.00)

Output `df3` should be:

```
            A       B
0        0.00  514.51
1        0.75  514.51
2        1.10  514.42
3        3.52  514.41
4        5.59  514.43
5        6.00  531.00
6        7.00  532.00
```

I´ve tried with `concat`, `merge` and `join`. No successfully.

Comment: You mean you want to include data from `df2` if values  in `A` are larger than last `df1[A]` value ?

Comment: I think you need to get the max from `df1['A']`, then filter `df2` based on this value and finally concat `df1` with the filtered `df2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate a Boolean mask on `df2`:

```
mask = df2['A'] >= df1['A'].iloc[-1]  # or df1['A'].max(), as required
```

Then use `pd.concat`:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2[mask]], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with second `df2` created by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for first `True` value and filter by `loc`:

```
df = df1.append(df2.loc[(df2['A'] >= df1['A'].values[-1]).idxmax():])
print (df)
      A       B
0  0.00  514.51
1  0.75  514.51
2  1.10  514.42
3  3.52  514.41
4  5.59  514.43
4  6.00  531.00
5  7.00  532.00
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df2.loc[(df2['A'] >= df1['A'].values[-1]).idxmax():])
     A      B
4  6.0  531.0
5  7.0  532.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
pd.concat([df1,df2[df2['A']>df1['A'].max()]])
```

Output:

```
      A       B
0  0.00  514.51
1  0.75  514.51
2  1.10  514.42
3  3.52  514.41
4  5.59  514.43
4  6.00  531.00
5  7.00  532.00
```